# Pre-requisites to learning docker

Tags: docker

So I have been trying to learn docker for a few days now, I am basically a windows user and I am trying to run docker on a ubuntu VM 14.04 , all I just wanted to ask was , WHAT are the pre-requisites to learning a Docker ?

Just like you can't learn `jQuery` , without the basics in `JavaScript` , just like you can't learn a framework like `laravel`, `magento`, `cakePHP` without the basics in `PHP` , just like you can't learn `LESS`, `SASS`, `SCSS`, without the basics in `CSS` in place , what would the pre-requisites for Docker be?

Can somebody list it out. Please done that I am not asking for an opinion here, I am asking for an **ABSOLUTE DEFINITIVE** answer to my question, which is, what are the pre-requisites for learning a tool like Docker?

Comment: I am suprised that a question with a specific context as this one , is being taged as `TOO BROAD` ! wow .

Comment: @jangroth i'll put it this way , this question is't the kind of question that is answerable by most users of Docker , simply because , even though i am asking a very basic question , answering it would take a reasonable amount of expertise,  `Why don't you just start reading about docker and lookup / ask / learn everything you don't understand on the way?` , Does't sound like good advice to me ,   about the shouting part ... "people here tend to lack common sense , so as to differentiate between a contextual question and a one that's seemingly so, but infact broad" !!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @jangroth , image it this way , if you were a astronaut on a mission to reach the moon , would you go build the  spaceship from scratch(as you suggest `Why don't you just start reading about docker and lookup / ask / learn everything you dont understand on the way?`) .... or would you go ask somebody whos'a already done it before ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to get Docker working on Ubuntu you should have a basic comprehension of these things

- how the bash works (at least how to handle files and folders)
- basics of networking on Linux/Ubuntu
- apt-get (installing packages like Nodejs or Postgres)
- the [Unix / Linux philosophy](http://opensource.com/business/15/2/how-linux-philosophy-affects-you)

Answer (score 4):

Since you are a Windows user, I'd recommend sticking to that well-known environment while you learn Docker. Learn one thing at a time.

Having that basic Windows knowledge, you should be able to follow on the [Learn Docker book](https://leanpub.com/dock) as long as you have the prerequisites stated in the book:

> Basic experience creating applications with **one** of the following technologies: .NET Core, Java, Node.JS, PHP or Python.

Chapter 2 of the book explains how to install Docker on various systems including Windows.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of that book.